# Jquery 2.1 and UI Dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery 2.1 and jquery-ui 1.8 and I get the [Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: ui-dialog]. Dialog works fine when using older version of jquery but i need to use it with 2.1 version.

Code:

```
$(document).find('body').append('<div id="dialog"></div>');

$("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
$("#dialog").dialog({  
    modal: true,  
    bgiframe: true,  
    width: 470,  
    height: 330,  
    autoOpen: false,  
    title: 'Are you sure you want to exit?'  
    });  

// LINK  
$("a.confirm").click(function(link) {  
     link.preventDefault(); 
    var theHREF = $(this).attr("href");
    var theREL = $(this).attr("rel");  
    var theMESSAGE = (theREL == undefined || theREL == '') ? defaultMessage : theREL;  
    var theICON = '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left;"></span>';               

    // set windows content  
    $('#dialog').html('<P>' + theICON + theMESSAGE + '</P>');  

    $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'buttons', {   
        "Logout MYCIC" : function() {  
            mycicExternalLinksProcessLogout(this);
            var url = exit + theHREF;
            alert(url);
            window.open(url);  
            //alert("link is "+exit+theHREF);
            },
        "Cancel" : function() {  
                mycicExternalLinksProcessCancel(this);
            },
        "Continue" : function() {               
                mycicExternalLinksProcessContinue(this); 
            }

        });  

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");  
    });
```

Comment: how about showing some code, please?

Comment: a certain version of jquery ui should has its corresponding version of jquery, so you may upgrade your jquery ui or downgrade jquery. any special functionality in the jquery 2.1 you will use?

Comment: the code runs on $(document).ready function. Thanks guys.

Comment: I cant downgrade the jquery but I will try to upgrade the ui. is there a newer version of the ui that will work with jquery 2.1? Thanks.

Comment: [jQuery UI 1.10.4](http://jqueryui.com/download/) is currently the latest.

Comment: but choose your version depending on IE version support.

Comment: Thank you guys... I will try this version and hope it will work. Will keep you guys updated. @Ruskin I need it to work with 7, 8, and 9... Fingures crossed :)

Comment: the 1.x branch includes support for ie 6,7,8, the 2.x branch does not

Comment: Thank you do much everyone for your quick reply and help. I am using the newer version of jquery ui 1.10.4 and it works perfectly... it does have some issues with ie7 but I am sure I can find figure that out :) You guys R O C K!!!